# Getting strange "unknown provider" error with extremely simple angular service

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build a very, very simple service and use it in angular, with all of my code listed below. But no matter what I try, I'm getting told ...

> Unknown provider: userServiceProvider <- userService

I'm pulling my hair out with this, so I'm hoping experienced eyes can see what I'm missing..

### app.js

```
(function () {
    angular.module('Application', [
        'kendo.directives',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap.drawer',
        'ui.check',
    ]);
})();
```

### identity.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var UserService = function ($http) {
        this.Find = function () {
            return this.$http.get("/member/identity").then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('Application')
        .service('UserService', [UserService,"$http"]);
})();
```

### controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var UserController = function (userService, $scope) {
        var _this = $scope;

        userService.Find().then(function (user) {
            _this.User = user;
        });
    };

    angular
        .module('Application')
        .controller('UserController',
            UserController, ['Application.UserService', "$scope"]
        );
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the sequence

```
angular
    .module('Application')
    .service('UserService', ["$http", UserService]);

angular
    .module('Application')
    .controller('UserController', ['Application.UserService', "$scope", UserController]
    );
```

dependencies to be injected comes before the function which defined the service/controller

also have the same case when defining and injecting the service as service names are case sensetive

Comment: Hrnm, that doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Comment: Oh I see. So I was putting them in the wrong order in two places. That explains it. Thank you so much! I'll accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.